# Serilog destructuring generated message contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, serilog

It seems that the serilog cannot deconstruct classes (contracts messages) automatically generated by Visual Studio when a service reference is added.

They are always serialized with unknow _typetag

```
 "fields": {
   "Request": {
     "_typeTag": "MessageContractType"
    }
  }
```

Why it is not automatically deconstructed?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the generated types have public *fields*, while Serilog's destructuring only inspects *properties*. A custom `IDestructuringPolicy` can achieve this.